# Prevent float wrap until elements have reached min-width

Tags: html, css, css-float, variable-width

I have variable-width HTML layout with a fixed-width menu to the left of a content `<div>` of variable width (set by css max-width and min-width). For very narrow browser windows I would like the content to wrap beneath the menu, and I am currently achieving this by setting `float:left` on both menu and content.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left; border: 1px black solid">Menu (200px wide)</div>
<div style="max-width: 800px; min-width: 300px; float:left; border: 1px black solid">Content div. This div has max-width: 800px; min-width 300px. It has enough text that it expands to its max-width if there is space available to do so.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, wrapping of the content `div` currently occurs as soon as the browser viewport is smaller than 1000px (menu width + content max-width). I would like to have the width of the content reduce first, and have the content wrap beneath the menu only when viewport is smaller than 500px wide (menu width + content min-width)

Is there a way to achieve this, either with my current arrangement of floated `<div>`s, or otherwise?

Comment: Minimal example code now included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check if this is the behavior you want.

**DEMO**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgmjX/)

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">Menu (200px wide)</div>
<div class="content">Content div. This div has max-width: 800px; min-width 300px. It has enough text that it expands to its max-width if there is space available to do so.</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px black solid
}

.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    border: 1px black solid
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {

.menu {
    float: none;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/WXFQz/

The solution is a simple media query - below a screen-width of *XYZpx* do *this*. If you've never heard of it before here's an article about it http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

For those of you who can't see the fiddle, here's the html and css :

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- it's possible to do it without this extra element. it's simply more intuitive this way -->
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

​

CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 1000px; /* your self defined 800px max-width for the content-div + 200px from the .menu's width */
    min-width: 200px;
}

.menu,
.content {
    height: 200px;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 200px; /* same as '.menu's width */
}

@media (max-width : 400px) {
    .menu {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    .content {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a demo of this from css-tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/PerfectFluidWidthLayout/

I hope this is good for you.

Comment: This example doesn't wrap under the menu when hitting his desired target.  It works nice though